# Rails 4.2 database.yml not reading rbenv-vars variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

My VPS has [rbenv-vars](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-vars) installed, I've located .rbenv-vars file within config directory inside rails app. I pretend to load database password inside of it, but I'm doing something wrong, because `rake db:create` gives me a no-password error. Rake works when I write the password as a string.

> config/.rbenv-vars

```
DB_PASS=my_db_password
```

---

> config/database.yml

```
  password: $DB_PASS                # Doesn't work
  #password: <%= ENV['DB_PASS'] %>  # Doesn't work
  # password: my_db_password        # Works
```

---

I get all variables running `rbenv vars`

> ssh > rbenv vars

```
export DB_PASS='my_db_password'
```

Comment: if you load variable into the vars file, you probably want to reload you shell

Answer (score 9):

via https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19256#issuecomment-102980786

You may need to do a

```
spring stop
```

and then try it again.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I know my variables are setup correctly

```
$ rbenv vars
# /Users/dave/code/project/.rbenv-vars
export SQL_SERVER_HOST='10.0.0.1'
export SQL_SERVER_PORT='1433'
export SQL_SERVER_USERNAME='project'
export SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD='password'
export SQL_SERVER_DATABASE='project-development'

$ cat config/database.yml
development:
  adapter:  sqlserver
  host:     <%= ENV['SQL_SERVER_HOST'] %>
  port:     <%= ENV['SQL_SERVER_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['SQL_SERVER_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['SQL_SERVER_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['SQL_SERVER_DATABASE'] %>
  mode:     dblib
```

Results in:

```
$ rails c
Inside TinyTds#initialize with {:dataserver=>nil, :host=>nil, :port=>nil, :username=>nil, :password=>nil, :database=>nil, :tds_version=>nil, :appname=>"project", :login_timeout=>nil, :timeout=>nil, :encoding=>nil, :azure=>nil}
/Users/dave/code/project/.gems/bundler/gems/tiny_tds-afef8218c3c0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:65:in `initialize': missing :host option if no :dataserver given (ArgumentError)
...
```

Maybe it's because `rbenv-vars` hasn't loaded the variables into my session yet?

Interestingly, when I put explicit values into the `config/database.yml`, it doesn't initialize `tiny_tds` on rails server boot, but on loading the first model:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.2)
[1] pry(main)> # No TinyTds#initialize!!!
[2] pry(main)> User.first
Inside TinyTds#initialize with {:dataserver=>nil, :host=>"10.0.0.1", :port=>1433, :username=>"project", :password=>"password", :database=>"project-development", :tds_version=>nil, :appname=>"project", :login_timeout=>nil, :timeout=>nil, :encoding=>nil, :azure=>nil}
  SQL (0.6ms)  USE [project-development]
  User Load (3.7ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [users].* FROM [users]  ORDER BY [users].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY'
=> #<User:0x007fb8a0929fe0
 id: 1,
 ...
```

So `rbenv-vars` seems to work fine once rails has been booted, but not during the boot?

Comment: Having a similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem setting `SECRET_KEY_BASE` in `secrets.yml` from an environment variable and was [guided to a solution by an `rbenv` developer](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars/issues/32).  Here's the basic explanation:

> Generally, `database.yml` should have access to environment variables.
>   But, for the sake of clear communication, let's remember that
>   `database.yml` doesn't evaluate itself; rather, **the process** that starts
>   Rails loads `database.yml` and evaluates variables within it. So, my
>   question for you is, who/what starts that process and how?
>
> How are you starting your Rails app and determining that `database.yml`
>   is broken? Are you using `rails server`, or `bundle exec`, or `unicorn`, or
>   something else? For the command that you're using, can you run `which -a <command>` and tell me the result?

In my case I was using Apache and Passenger, so this could be resolved by adding the following to the Apache config for my application (i.e `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my_app.conf`):

> PassengerRuby /home/my_username/.rbenv/shims/ruby